# How to send data from angularjs to cakephp

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, ionic2

I have all my actions done in cakephp. I was using a platform in client side, and now I decided to migrate to Ionic/angularjs, but as I saw, they do not "talk" with each other. Angular uses Content-Type: application/json that cakePHP does not read with request->data or request->query.

I found some workarounds that I need to change all the actions in my server side. Is there another way to keep it without changes? I´d like to keep it working in the old client version too.

[Edited]
In algularjs I´m using $http service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your problem.

If you send json data to your server with a post request, you can get data with a cakephp application easily:

```
jsonData = {data: [{key: 'a', value: 'b'}, {key: 'a', value: 'b'}]};
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://example.com/Tests',
  data: jsonData
}
$http(req);
```

Then in your controller you can get data:

```
class MyController extends AppController{
    // ...

    public function action(){
         debug($this->request->data);
         // you have your data from your angularjs app
         // ['data' =>  [['key' => 'a', value => 'b'], ['key' => 'a', value => 'b']]];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephane Stéphane, I created an angular test.html using the service.js that I´m using with Ionic. Pure angular send the data as POST and return the json perfectly, the same service ($http) being called by Ionic sends the data as OPTIONS and return nothing. So the problem seams to be with Ionic. I still don´t know what.

Comment: I can´t even see the data sent in the chrome debug network (in your exemple: key, value)  when sending by Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem changing the $http header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", I saw this [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/http-post-not-sending-data/47452/5)

```
body = 'cel=xxxx&pass=zczx';
            var req = {
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://localhost/cakefacility/usuarios/checkUsuario.json',
              data: body,
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }
            $http(req);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sending Data from angular to cakephp project you need to create REST API at cakephp project for creating REST API you can follow my forked [github repo](https://github.com/hareshpatel1990/cakephp3restapi).

After Creating API in cakephp project you just call API like:

For Call API by GET:

```
$http.get("<REST API URL>").then(function(response) {
   ......
   ......
});
```

For Call API by POST:

```
$http.post(<REST API URL>, <DATA TO SEND>).success(function(data, status) {
.......
.......
});
```